# How do you search for a phrase on a page in Chrome? (Not a string match)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, search, find

I'm using Chrome on a Mac, and want to be able to easily search for a phrase on a page, not an exact string match.

For instance, on this page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events

If I hit command+F (or ctrl+F) and enter *load*

it shows me 63 instances on the page where *load* appears.

But I just want to find instances where the phrase *load* appears (which would **exclude** the words *loading* or *download*).

When searching for *"load"* it looks for an exact string match which includes the quotes.

When adding *-loading*, it also looks for an exact string match.

When I Google search for various combinations of "advanced search find in page chrome browser" I get way too many results and it's hard to research.

Comment: How about searching for "load " with a space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RegEx Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regex-search/bcdabfmndggphffkchfdcekcokmbnkjl) lets you search for things inside a web page using regular expressions. If you're new to regular expressions (as I am) then look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). You can easily find what you're looking for quickly.

To find (as in your example), a single phrase, such as `load` then, all you need to type is `\bload\b`.

If you separate this, you get `\b` and `load` and `\b`.

`\b` is an *anchor*. It is true at a *word boundary*. More info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (same website as above, different page). Simply put, you use this for seperate words.

Here is this example working in the website in your question:

[image].

RegEx can be very powerful, so this is using the extension as a very low-use. If you ever need, you can use this for things like wildcards etc. (which by default Chrome does not provide)

Answer (score 4):

One way to filter down is to search for "`load`" that is a space followed by the word followed by another space. This will unfortunately not handle cases where the word is next to punctuation, but it will find only instances of "load" and not "loading" for example.